# React Data Grid, how can I remove a row?

Tags: reactjs

I using the example provided by React, and I want to have a button on every row and when it is clicked a row to be deleted.

https://codesandbox.io/s/5vy2q8owj4?from-embed

I am new to reactjs, it is possible to do it?

What I thought to do is to add another row with a button and inside the component to have a function like this, I don't know how to call this function from the outside:

```
{ key: "", name: "", formatter: () => <button onClick={() => 
this.deleteRows(title)}>Delete</button>}

deleteRows = (id) => {
    let rows = this.state.rows.slice()
    rows = rows.filter(row => row.id !== id)
    this.setState({ rows })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the cell actions example http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/examples/cell-actions

Comment: Hi Andry, I tried and is not working, what I managed to do is to add a column:   { key: "", name: "", formatter: () => <button onClick={() => this.deleteRows(title)}>Delete</button>} but is not working

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried and specifically what you're expecting and what isn't working. The answer to the only question you've asked, "is it possible," is "yes."

Comment: I just edited my question: Thanks andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You may use [getCellActions](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/docs/ReactDataGrid#getcellactions) to achieve this. Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5091lpolzk

Comment: Thanks Rafael, I have one more question, but I will ask in a different question area.. since will help others to solve this problem.

Comment: Rafael, I just done some modifications and my rows does not contain index:0 and the id are generated, based on similar example as yours the splice method is not deleting the right row, how can I use splice without using the index of the row?

Comment: rows data is [name, city, number, extra] the splice is not working, can the splice be done without using the index?

Comment: `getCellActions` is a good advice. However the sample you've provided has a few bugs related to how array indexes are handled internally. For example you can't delete the last row, and as you move on deleting rows the little arrows start to skew.

Comment: @NicoAndrade any idea how can I fix that?